# PowerShell condition - result length > 0 or something like that

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

I have a simple one line command that list contents of some remote share

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\some_path\" -Recurse | Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) }
```

I need to send an email in case there are no files in this folder.

So I found code that should send an email:

```
if ($Condition) {
    Send-MailMessage -From "sender@example.com" -To "receiver@example.com" -Subject "Condition met" -Body "The condition you specified has been met." -SmtpServer "smtp.example.com"
}
```

However, I'm not sure how should I define this $Condition in case there is nothing in this folder.

Maybe something like this:

```
$Condition = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\some_path\" -Recurse | Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | length>0
```

Thanks.

Comment: So if there _is_ a file in the share, but the file(s) is all empty - do you still want to send the email?

Comment: I don't. Just when there is nothing in folder send an email.

Comment: In that case you can do `if(-not(Get-ChildItem -Path "\\some_path\" -Recurse -File)){ ... }` - email will be sent if no files were found

Comment: At this moment I'm missing information on local smtp server so cannot test it, but as soon as I get it, I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need an SMTP server to test how `if(-not(Get-ChildItem ...)){ "in if" }else{ "in else" }` works :)

Comment: you're right. it does work :)